# Count with condition in xquery

Tags: function, count, xquery, conditional-statements

I have a node with a child node, that has a content like this:

```
<parent>
  <child>a</child>
  <child>b</child>
  <child>c</child>
  <child>a</child>
  <child>c</child>
</parent>
```

I want to count the number of childs that have an 'a' as content.

So far I've tried:

```
count($node/child/'a')
```

But that gives me only the number of all childs.
What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let $parent :=
  <parent>
    <child>a</child>
    <child>b</child>
    <child>c</child>
    <child>a</child>
    <child>c</child>
  </parent>
return count($parent/child[text() = 'a'])
```

It would also count `<child>a<foobar/>b</child>`, since the text node `a` is found. To compare all text contexts, you can use `$parent/child[. = 'a']`.

Comment: I almost got that your way, just forget a character.. and I wos wondering and wondering.. thank you very much :)